# Error when integrating with youtube-ios-player-helper third party library on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to play a YouTube video with the [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/) library, but I am encountering an error at runtime:

> ```
> Received error rendering template: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 258.)"
> ```

Answer (score 40):

In YTPlayerView.m

Edit:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YTPlayerView-iframe-player"
                                                 ofType:@"html"
                                            inDirectory:@"Assets"];
```

To:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YTPlayerView-iframe-player"
                                                 ofType:@"html"];
```

Hope to help you!

Comment: I have replaced the code. but it shows some texts with out playing video

Answer (score 6):

You need **copy** Assets/YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html to main bundle to fix this issue.

**or** just put into bundle, and replace where App starts to look for

```
/*NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YTPlayerView-iframe-player"
     ofType:@"html"
     inDirectory:@"Assets"];*/

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YTPlayerView-iframe-player" ofType:@"html"];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Drag and drop**

YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html

YTPlayerView.h

YTPlayerView.m

files in your project.

**Add bridging header and use this:**

```
#import "YTPlayerView.h"
```

**Go to  YTPlayerView.m file :**

Find :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YTPlayerView-iframe-player"
                                                 ofType:@"html"
                                            inDirectory:@"Assets"];
```

**Change to :**

```
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YTPlayerView-iframe-player"
                                                     ofType:@"html"];
```

**In your View Controller:**

use :

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,YTPlayerViewDelegate {

   var playerView = YTPlayerView()
```

**fetch videoID and load :**

```
self.playerView.load(withVideoId: videoID)

self.playerView.playVideo()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't give a version of the plugin you have a problem with.
In case this is  1.5, there is a bug discussed here: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/160.

It is already fixed in master, so, assuming you are using Cocoapods, you may do this:

```
pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', :git=>'https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper', :commit=>'head'
```